# `You don't have permission` to view `User:` on MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

Suddenly (AFAIK) I can't view any userspaces on my MediaWiki install (whether I'm logged in as Admin or not). Instead I'm getting this error:

```
You don't have permission to access /wiki/User:stevenarntson on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use
an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I have been doing some work in `common.css` and `localsettings.php`, but nothing that I'd think would have an effect like this.

What might be causing this behavior?

Comment: Is the server apache based? (check the HTTP response headers of the request by going to redbot.org and typing in the URL that's giving the permission denied error and look for the line that starts with `Server`).

Comment: got such, if used www instead of non-www or vise versa

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by contacting my hosting provider (Namecheap). Their instance of Apache's [mod_security](https://www.modsecurity.org/) functionality had been triggered by those pages. The tech there whitelisted a couple of things w/r/t those pages, and the site is now functioning well.